# Get the last query that run on a specific table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know i can get the last queries on a specific DB, but is there an option to get specific queries that were perform on a specific table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following statement (adapted from a solution given in the related question under **References**):

```
SELECT  d.plan_handle ,
        d.sql_handle ,
        e.text

FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats d
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(d.plan_handle) AS e
WHERE e.text LIKE '%[dbo].[Table1]%'; --[dbo].[Table1] is the name of the table
```

**References**:

[A related question on SO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/can-i-see-historical-queries-run-on-a-sql-server-database)